# IBDesignable NSTextField in Swift

Tags: swift, interface-builder, nstextfield, ibdesignable

Is it possible to have a IBDesignable NSTextField in swift like this

```
@IBDesignable public class CustomTextView: NSTextField {

    public override func prepareForInterfaceBuilder() {
        self.stringValue = "test"
    }

}
```

I am able to work with NSView as IBDesignable with no issue, however when I use it with NSTextField the "Designables: Up to date" label in the Interface Builder does not show up.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It appears that NSTextField-overloaded classes don't support custom viewing in Interface Builder.  Your IBInspectables will appear in the inspector, but IB will not display any custom stuff

Just putting this here as I trip up on this occasionally and I hope that I find this when I search for it next!